# React Semantic UI How to use "Link"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm new to semantic-ui. I try to map Menu Items with lodash. But unfortunately I can't routing my elements.

Here is my code

```
</Menu.Item>
    {_.map(menuItems, item => <Menu.Item {...item} />)}
</Menu.Menu>
```

And its my menu object

```
const menuItems= [
  { as: "a", content: "About Us", key: "about", path:"/about"},
  { as: "a", content: "Contact", key: "contact", path:"/contact"}
];
```

so I want to Link my menu with react-router. I try everythink but i cant solve the problem

**It returns**

```
 <a path="/about" ........>
```

But I want to get

```
<Link path="/about".....>
```

How can i do solve the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it `as={Link}`.

So basically your objects should reflect that:

```
const menuItems= [
  { as: Link, content: "About Us", key: "about", path:"/about"},
  { as: Link, content: "Contact", key: "contact", path:"/contact"}
];
```

Comment: I try that. It returns "Warning: <Link /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements." and return Links not clickable.

Comment: @Ryoush note that it should be `as: Link` (Link is a variable) and not `as:'Link'` (string)

Comment: You have returned me from a big mistake. I'm never thinking of that. Thank you :)